# What is your preferred distortion plug-in?

Tags: distortion, plugin, fun

What is your most used distortion plug-in?

With which other methods do you add distortion?

What are some of the best results you have achieved when applying distortion?

Answer (score 3):

For sick and extreme effects... Decapitator! (I love this plugin)

http://www.soundtoys.com/products/Decapitator/

For specific tasks... Speakerphone..

http://www.audioease.com/Pages/Speakerphone/speakerphone.html

Also, plugins like Guitar Rig, Amplitube and GTR have lots of interesting distortion/overdrive components, plus a ton of invaluable tools for sound design.

Comment: +1 on Decapitator! everything Sound Toys makes is solid gold.

Answer (score 2):

[ohmicide!!!](http://www.ohmforce.com/ViewProduct.do?p=Ohmicide)

absolutely wicked distortion, multi-band (4 bands), tons of interesting filters, endless mutations...

Comment: I absolutely love OhmForce plugins.

Answer (score 2):

I love Isotope Trash.  very useful features.  Pre COmpressor, pre-eq, post eq, tons of distortions, cabinet modeling, and some bells and whistles - delays and such (the analog delay is nice and thick).

Answer (score 1):

I have reached for the SansAmp PSA-1 many, many times. Great, versatile little plug-in.

[image: SansAmp PSA-1]
<sub>(source: [avid.com](https://www.avid.com/static/resources/common/images/products/cw_m260xm260_sansampPSA.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Audio Damage has a great multi-band distortion plugin called [Kombinat](http://www.audiodamage.com/effects/product.php?pid=AD019).

Answer (score 0):

SansAmp, Massey TapeHead, and Waves L1 - seriously, push that puppy hard to get a very unique distortion effect!

Answer (score 0):

Something you'll probably find from me, a lot, is free plug-ins.

I use Atomsplitter's Destroyr almost exclusively for OD/Distortion... The only times it hasn't been as effective as I've wanted it, I either wanted more bitcrushing (which I use [CMT Bitcrusher](http://freemusicsoftware.org/722)) or when I want a smoother overdrive, which I'll use just about any amp simulator for.

Answer (score 0):

I have really come to like the amp simulater that is in Nuendo 4.  I've found it versatile, and usefull when I want to dirty something up.  I almost always still mix in the original clean track with the distorted one.  Depends on the situation of course.

I'm limited in third party plug-ins (I only have three), therefore I have to find creative ways to work with what I got.  I find most of the fun in sound design comes from that.